# How to find out the amount scrolled in a QScrollArea

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qscrollarea

I have a QScrollArea which contains a QWidget. The scroll area only allows to scroll vertically. How can I find out by how many pixels the QWidget is scrolled? I found scrollContentsBy() in the documentation but not the equivalent getter. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MyScrollArea -> verticalScrollBar() -> value()`.